# Multiprocessing (pool.map) failing with 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Can't figure out this error return by `multiprocessing.pool.map`. Would be great to get some help.

Here's a simplified version of the setup:
I have two methods in a class. When an object of the class gets instantiated, the `_get_topics()` method is executed. This method then executes the `_execute_ners()` method by means of multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 

class NaturalCommunication:

    def __init__(self, 
                 text,
                 **kwargs):

        self.text = text
        self.topics = self._get_topics()
    
    def _get_topics(self):
        """
        Extract topics from text.
        """
        p = Pool(processes=3)
        data = p.map(self._execute_ners, ['ner1', 'ner2', 'ner3'])
        p.close()

        return data

    def _execute_ners(self, ner_name:str) -> dict:
        entities = {}
        for i, sentence in enumerate(self.text.sents):
            entities[i] = []

            if ner_name == 'ner1': 
                # Execute ner number 1
                ner = NerNumberOne(#some config files)
                ner.get_entities(#some config files)
                entities[i] += ner.entities #get entities return from ner1
            
            if ner_name == 'ner2':
                # Execute ner number 2
                ner = NerNumberTwo(#some config files)
                ner.get_entities(#some config files)
                entities[i] += ner.entities #get entities return from ner2

            if ner_name == 'ner3':  
                ner = NerNumberThree(#some config files)
                ner.get_entities(#some config files)
                entities[i] += ner.entities #get entities return from ner3

        return entities
```

I believe the problem that occurs is somehow because of the format of what is being returned in `entities`. If I alter `_execute_ners()` to simply return 'string', the data variable in `_get_topics()` populates successfully. In this case, `_execute_ners()` returns a dictionary populated with what we have defined to be `StackExchangeEntity` objects (you can see the format of what is return in the error statement below.

Here is the error output on the line `data = p.map(...)`:

> Exception has occurred: MaybeEncodingError
> Error sending result: '[{0: [StackExchangeEntity(('visa', 'ner1'))], 1: [StackExchangeEntity(('time', 'ner3')), StackExchangeEntity(('time', 'ner2'))]}]'. Reason: 'TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable")'

This seems to be an internal error within the pool.map module or am I missing something?

Comment: I would suggest adding the whole exception trace, to get a better view of what's going on

Comment: Is `NaturalCommunication` created in your `if __name__=='__main__':` block?  There's a chicken-and-egg thing here.  If the object also gets instantiated when initializing the subprocesses, then each subprocess will try to start more subprocesses.